# How can I use Dynamic key in Joi

Tags: input, dynamic, key, runtime, joi

I am a beginner in Joi.

I want to make the following 'folderContent' a dynamic value, it can be 'onlySubject' or 'otherDetails' or whatever I will give as input during runtime.

Details: In the schema('bodySchema') , there is a object ('superObject')under which there is another object ('folderContent'), within that there is a string ('subject')

```
const bodySchema=Joi.object({
superObject: Joi.object()
    .when('grade', {
      is: 'class6',
      then: {
        folderContent: Joi.object({
            subject: Joi.string(),
          }),
      },
    })
});
```

So the input looks like the following where instead of 'folderContent' I  want to give dynamic key value

```
"superObject": {
        "folderContent": {
            "subject": "Geography"
        }
    }
```

I have tried the followings, but did not work:
1)superObject: Joi.object()
.when('grade', {
is: 'class6',
then: {

```
    folderContent: Joi.object()
      .keys({
        subject: Joi.string(),
      })
      .unknown(true),
    
  },
})
```

2)superObject: Joi.object()
.when('grade', {
is: 'class6',
then: {

```
    folderContent: Joi.object()
      ({
        subject: Joi.string(),
      })
      .unknown(true),
    
  },
})
```

Error is coming when I give input as 'onlySubject' for 'folderContent'
{
"success": false,
"exception": "InvalidBodyParameters",
"message": ""superObject.onlySubject" is not allowed",
"stack": "ValidationError: "superObject.onlySubject" is not allowed"
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, the following is working fine. With the help of your pattern it worked, thank you so much.

```
superObject
: Joi.object()

    .when(‘grade’, {
      is: ‘class6’,
      then: Joi.object().pattern(
        Joi.string(),
        Joi.object({
          subject: Joi.string(),
        })
      ),
    })
    .when(‘grade’, {
      is: ‘class5’,
      then: Joi.object().pattern(
        Joi.string(),
        Joi.object({
          subject: Joi.string(),
          Pattern: Joi.string(),
        })
      ),
    }),
```

Answer (score 1):

If your object has this structure:

```
{ 
  superObject: {
    folderContent: {
      subject: "Geography"
    }
  }
}
```

and `folderContent` can be a dynamic string key, you can use [object.pattern()](https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/master/API.md#objectpatternpattern-schema-options):

```
Joi.object({
  superObject: Joi.object().pattern(
    Joi.string(),
    Joi.object({
        subject: Joi.string()
    })
  )
})
```

This way, your `superObject` object can contain any key you want, and that key must contain another object with the key `subject`.

For instance, this object will be valid:

```
{ 
  superObject: {
    aaabbbccc: {
      subject: "Geography"
    }
  }
}
```

You can change the key `aaabbbcc` to whatever you want, as long as you keep the keys `superObject` and `subject`.

**EDIT**: here's an alternative/simpltification to your conditions:

```
Joi.object({
  superObject: Joi.object().pattern(
    Joi.string(),
    Joi.object({
        subject: Joi.string(),
        pattern: Joi.string().when('...grade', {
          is: 'class6', 
          then: Joi.forbidden() 
        })
    })
  )
})
```

What we are "saying" here is that if `grade` is `class6` then the `pattern` is forbidden, otherwise it will be valid along with the `subject`. You can even add `Joi.string().valid('class6', 'class7')` if those are the only valid options.

Comment: What about the condition? can we add condition to the  code you have suggested 

.when('grade', {
      is: 'class6',
      then: {

Comment: I am asking this, because if it is grade 6 there is only one 'subject' string, whereas if it is grade 7, there are two strings 'subject' and 'pattern'

Comment: @user15658079 I've updated my answer with another example.